# What is for folders API?

Tags: deezer

There is an endpoint for folders but I can't see this feature on `Deezer` apps. I tried to add new folders via `API` but can't see it on Deezer web player. Is it a new feature that has been not implemented?

Comment: have you taken efforts for finding solution? Please add your findings

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the "folder" functionnality as been deprecated on the website, that's why you can't see anything about it. We will deprecate it too in the API documentation in order not to confuse developers.